# UIImagePickerController using addSubView leaves white margin at the top of view

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I need to add UIImagePickerController in camera mode using addSubView. I have written code for it but it leaves white space at the top of the view.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
NSLog(@"ViewDidAppear");

OverlayView *overlay = [[OverlayView alloc]
                        initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGTH)];

//create a new image picker instance
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
self.picker.delegate = self;
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){
    //set source to video!
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    //hide all controls
    picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    picker.navigationBarHidden = NO;
    picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
    picker.editing = NO;
    //make the video preview full size
    picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    slider.value = 1;

    picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(picker.cameraViewTransform,slider.value, slider.value);
    //set our custom overlay view
    picker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
    [picker.view addSubview:slider];
    //show picker


    [picker.view addSubview:capture];
    [picker.view addSubview:library];
    //[picker.view addSubview:multicapture];

    [capture addTarget:self action:@selector(takepicture) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [library addTarget:self action:@selector(goToLibrary) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:picker.view];
    [picker viewWillAppear:YES];
    [picker viewDidAppear:YES];

}else{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Test Text" message:@"Camera is Not Availble" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

[overlay release];
```

}

Can anyone please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you create any views in IB with simulated metrics? I've found sometimes using them will cause strange alignment behavior for complicated view hierarchies (probably due to my own mis-structuring)

Comment: I have created simple tab bar based app. this code is written on view contoller placed on one tab item

Comment: NSLog the value of your SCREEN_HEIGHT constant (are you sure you spelled it right? In your code above you have 'SCREEN_HEIGTH')

Comment: Answer me one thing only. Is your `UIImagePickerController` view is also the root view of your app?

Comment: no UIImagePickerController is not the root view. TabBarController is the rootview of the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As kante0 says, that white margin is the status bar disappeared. If you want to show the status bar, use kante0's solution:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
[self.view addSubview:picker.view];
```

If you don't want to show the status bar (typically when you show the camera preview), use this piece of code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
[self.view setFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

// Place your overlay view here

[self.view addSubview:picker.view];
```

But you have to remember that when the pickerview is removed, if you want to show again the status bar, you'll need to do this:

```
[picker.view removeFromSuperview];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
[self.view setFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

// If you need to place elements programmatically, do it here
```

Comment: I have some problem using with this. I have added the UIImagePickerViewController as subview to self.view. But when using UIImagePickerViewController Library, when i click that list view of Images or scrolling that list view, it will hide/remove all the list of images. what is wrong in that?. Can you help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

Look into `NSScreen` for getting accurate dimensions. Double check that you have the height value correct. For example, you could do this:

```
int width = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size.width;
int height = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size.height;
```

Answer (score 1):

Is not a white margin, is status bar disappearing.

I solved the problem with:

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];