# Cannot remove white space above view in a clone of UIImagePickerControler

Tags: objective-c, cordova, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to remove a white space that shows above my image picker view. I'm using [this clone](https://github.com/questbeat/QBImagePicker) of `UIImagePickerController`. You can see in this picture:

[image: white space above image picker]

It's the white space between the gray bar at the top of the screenshot and the images. From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880364/uiimagepickercontroller-breaks-status-bar-appearance) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028029/uiimagepickercontroller-using-addsubview-leaves-white-margin-at-the-top-of-view), it seems the problem is the image picker leaving space for the status bar. But none of those solutions have worked for me. My app is built with [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) so I've also tried hiding the status bar using [this plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar/) but it didn't work. The size of the space simply increased because the statusbar was no longer present. The plugin relies on `setStatusBarHidden:YES` on the main `UIApplication` of the app, so it's similar to one of the suggestions in those other threads.

What else can I try to fix this?